# Examples for SOLID principles in ASP.Net C# web form

Tags: c#, webforms, code-behind, solid-principles

I am learning SOLID principles and find lot of articles taking business classes as example.

SOLID principles are to decouple the classes where as ASP.NET ( ASP.NET web forms development which is mainly event based) web forms code behind tightly coupled with controls. So I would like to see practical examples of SOLID principles in web form code behind files.

Please note that I don't want MVC.

Any links to sites/books which explain in detail will also helps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use MVC and still want to have separation in layers then you should try considering MVP pattern this is a very good article showing how to use it in asp.net http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14642/Model-View-Presenter-with-ASP-NET

also have a look at http://webformsmvp.com/

Regards.

Comment: my actual question was related to asp.net not mvc and mvp. but it seems we should separate the concerns to follow SOLID principles. any how thnx for the references.

Comment: MVP and MVC are actually design patterns & practices(Solid Principles) used by many enterprise projects to separate layers of concern. You can implement MVP in asp.net, winform,WPF apps, silverlight apps. same goes with MVC. You should have a look at MVP and MVC how it separates the layers then you will easily get your answer.

Comment: That second link does not look valid anymore.